# Можно как-то проверить на лету есть ли в БД такой логин?

Tags: php, mysql

Можно как-то проверить на лету есть ли в БД такой логин?

Comment: что значит налету? надо взять этот логин и запросом проверить есть ли уже такая запись в бд

Comment: на ajax разве что?

Comment: без перезагрузки страницы

Answer (score 2):

В своем простом проявлении как-то так. Накидал на скорую руку, если где ошибки - звыняйте :)

**LoginExists.php**

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['login']) && is_string($_POST['login'])) {
    //  подключение к бд
    $login = '"'. mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']) .'"';
    if(!mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT login FROM users WHERE login=' . $login))) {
        echo 'Логин '. $login .' - cвободен'; 
    }
    else {
        echo 'К сожалению логин '. $login .' - занят';
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML & JavaScript**

```
<!-- javascript -->

<script type="text/javascript">
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

function liveLoginCheckInit() {
   var loginInput = document.getElementById("loginInput");
   request.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           document.getElementById("loginCheckResult").innerHTML = this.responseText
       }
   }
   loginInput.addEventListener( "blur", function() {

       request.open("POST", "/LoginExists.php", true);
       request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       request.send("login=" + this.value);

   }, false )
}

window.addEventListener( "load", liveLoginCheckInit, false );
</script>

<!-- html -->
<form method="POST" action="">
<!-- тут твоя форма, я напишу только инпут login, т.к. остальное, в данном примере -->
    <!-- не является принципиальным -->

    <input type="text" id="loginInput" name="login">
    <span id="loginCheckResult"><!-- сюда будем подгружать ответ сервера --></span>

</form>
```

PS: проверка логина происходит при потере фокуса у поля "loginInput"
PPS: поправил код, было пару ошибок.

**UPD**

**Jquery Version**

```
<!-- сначала подключаем prototype для того что бы можно было с ним работать -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

//  пример того-же JS скрипта с использованием jquery
//  скачать последнюю версию jquery можно по ссылке
//  http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginInput").blur(function() {

    //  подробнее о методе $.post можно почитать перейдя по ссылке ниже
    //  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
    $.post('/LoginExists.php', {login:$(this).val()}, function(serverResponse) {
            //  функция обработчик ответа сервера
            $("#loginCheckResult").html(serverResponse);
        })
    })
})
</script>
```

**Prototype version**

```
<!-- сначало подключаем prototype для того что бы можно было с ним работать -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/prototype.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

//  пример того-же JS скрипта с использованием prototype
//  скачать последнюю версию можно по ссылке
//  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js

Event.observe( window, "load", function() {

    Event.observe( "loginInput", "blur", function() {

//  подробнее о методе ajax'e в prototype
    //      можно почитать перейдя по ссылке ниже
//  http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/

//  и вот еще хорошая статья 
//  http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/introduction-to-ajax

    new Ajax.Request("/LoginExists.php", {
        parameters: {'login':this.value},
        onSuccess: function(request) {
                //  функция обработчик ответа сервера
            $("loginCheckResult").innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    })

});

})

</script>
```

PS:естественно код сервера остается прежний... HTML(если это можно так назвать :)) я тоже не трогал

PPS: не люблю jquery :P

Comment: не работает, я выложил сюда http://hashcode.ru/questions/56678/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: это:
    $login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);

нужно заменить на это:
    $login = "'"mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login'])."'";

Comment: Я согласен, просто писал тогда на скорую руку... Если быть точным то перед перекуром, вот и прощелкал...